# Multilayer perceptron assumptions

Tags: neural-networks, residuals, assumptions

I have a hard time finding what assumptions there is for the Multilayer perceptron with MSE as a loss function. I know that for linear regression there is assumptions about the observations being iid, normal distribution of residuals and that the residuals should show a random pattern.

I have read in some articles that neural networks does not have any model assumptions, although in other articles it seems that some of the linear regression assumptions hold for neural networks to?

So I'm wondering what assumptions are there for the multilayer perceptron and how strict are these assumptions? is there an assumption about random residuals for example?

Would really appreciate if someone could tell me about these assumptions.